# Python schedule :missing 1 required positional argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, schedule

This is my code.

```
from API.helpers import get_weather_data, json_to_df, create_dict
import schedule, time

URL = 'https://pm1aapplicantsdata.blob.core.windows.net/databases/CitiesWeather/CitiesWeather.csv'
columns = ["name","sys.country","main.temp",
           "main.humidity","main.pressure",
           "visibility", "wind.speed"]

def weather_api(URL):
    dict = create_dict(URL)
    for city, code in dict.items():
        data = get_weather_data(city, code)
        json_to_df(data, columns)

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(weather_api())
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

What I want to do is to run it on some regular intervals. However, I am getting an error saying `"weather_api() missing 1 required positional argument: 'URL'"`. I've tried to pass it into the schedule `schedule.every(10).minutes.do(weather_api(URL))` but then I am getting `the first argument must be callable` error. Also in this case...

```
def weather_api():
    URL = 'https://pm1aapplicantsdata.blob.core.windows.net/databases/CitiesWeather/CitiesWeather.csv'
    dict = create_dict(URL)
    for city, code in dict.items():
        data = get_weather_data(city, code)
        json_to_df(data, columns)

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(weather_api())
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

...the error remains. I have tried to use Advanced Python Scheduler before but the problem was same. My script works fine otherwise. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the source code of schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py#L371-L392)

You may want to use `schedule.every(10).minutes.do(weather_api, URL)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're supposed to send an argument inside `.do()`, but about the second exception, you should run it like this:

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(weather_api)
```

instead of `weather_api()`.

`.do()` expects a function as a parameter, and `weather_api` is the function you need to send, not the data that it returns (by adding the `()` to it).